# Which of the following sets are countable?

Tags: proof-verification

a) $[0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$

b) $P(\mathbb Q)$

c) $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q $

d) $\{(a, b) ∈ \mathbb R\times\mathbb R | a, b \in\mathbb N\}$

**I answered a) and d)**

a) any intersection between two sets where one if finite must be countable

b) by definition, any power set of $\mathbb Z, \mathbb Q, \mathbb N$ is not countable

c) $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ does not remove the irrational numbers from $\mathbb R$ hence it remains uncountable.

d) Wasn't too sure about this one to be honest, the $a,b\in\mathbb N$ implies that $a$ and $b$ must be aligned with the cardinality of N, which is a countable set? But the domain is the plane of real numbers..

Am I wrong?

Comment: note that D is really just the set $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ which has the cardinality of $\Bbb N$

Comment: In a) none of the two sets are finite.

Comment: @Seven woops, but if there exists an intersection between the two then must there not be a finite realm?

Comment: No, the intersection of two infinite sets can be infinite. It is still countable, but because of other reasons. And any power set of $\mathbb N,\mathbb Z,\mathbb Q$ is not countable, but that is not by definition.

Answer (score 1):

> a) any intersection between two sets where one if finite must be countable

**Irrelevant**. While the statement is correct, it does not apply to the set $[0,1]\cap\mathbb Q$ since none of the two sets is finite.

> b) by definition, any power set of Z,Q,N is not countable

**Wrong**. That is not true "by definition". There is a theorem that shows that.

> c) $\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q$ does not remove the irrational numbers from $\mathbb R$ hence it remains uncountable.

**Circular**. Your statement "proves" that the set of irrational numbers ($\mathbb R\setminus\mathbb Q$) is irrational because the set of irrational numbers is irrational. Did you prove that irrational numbers are uncountable in your class before?

> d) Wasn't too sure about this one to be honest, the a,bEN implies that a and b must be aligned with the cardinality of N, which is a countable set? But the domain is the plane of real numbers..

The fact that the domain is the real numbers means nothing. For example, $\{a\in\mathbb R: a\in\mathbb N\}$ is a countable set.

Comment: Alright then, so I'm assuming that my answers (a & d) are wrong? It appears that only d) is a countable set?

Comment: @Rozan I never said any of your claims are *wrong*. I only said they are not well justified. For example, $\mathbb N\cap \mathbb N$ is a countable set. However, it is not countable because the intersection of a finite set with any set is countable. That is not a correct justification, even though the statement I am trying to justify is correct.

Comment: I see, my justifications stem from a hazy amalgamation of ideas taken from various youtube videos, thank you for correcting me!